# Architecture of 61131 program

Tags: plc, iec61131-3

In my 61131 program I have Objects/Information that needs to be shared between different program parts. What is best practice regarding this, should the Objects that needs to be shared be VAR in the PRG POU or global in a GVL?

From "high-level" programming I'm skeptical about global data, but this is maybe necessary?

Thanks for any input about best practice architectures in 61131.

Comment: there is horrific stuff outside in 61131 caused by multiple reasons (bad IDEs, unskilled programmers etc.)... Don' descent into the 61131 architectue hell outside there. I have been down there too often. Try to bring your best practices from your high-level programming to 61131 and make a nice modern architecture! Believe it or not, you can write SOLID code in 61131 too! The time has come!

Comment: This is exactly my goal, to find a good architecture for 61131, using all applicable stuff that we have learned in high level programming in the last 20 years. Any pointers, on- or off-topic, about this is highly welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a `STRUCT` to global variables that has all the global data for a one component, for example a struct called `ST_CoolingSystem` which has the required global data for program handling the cooling system etc.

Other approach would be a method / property for the `PROGRAM`POU. It of course required Codesys 3 or similar. This way you could create a getter for variable / struct to the program or function block itself such as `PRG_CoolingSystem.GetData()` which returns the struct or reference to it.

**Update:**

One way to use OOP features is to add a property that returns a reference to data struct. **NOTE: This works in TwinCAT 3, should also work in other IEC 61131-3 systems that have the new features.**

Let's say we have a struct `ST_Cooling`

```
TYPE ST_Cooling :
STRUCT
    //Commands
    RunCooling          : REAL;
    TemperatureSetpoint : REAL;

    //Status
    MotorRunning        : BOOL;
    CurrentTemperature  : REAL;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

And we also have a function block `FB_Cooling`

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Cooling
VAR_INPUT
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
END_VAR
VAR
    MotorRunCmd AT %Q*  : BOOL;
    Data_               : ST_Cooling; //"Private" of data struct
END_VAR


IF Data_.RunCooling THEN
    //Do something
    MotorRunCmd := TRUE;

    //Update status
    Data_.MotorRunning := TRUE;
ELSE
    //Do something
    MotorRunCmd := FALSE;

    //Update status
    data_.MotorRunning := FALSE;
END_IF
```

We can add a `PROPERTY`to `FB_Cooling` that can be used to retrieve the struct and read and edit it. Because it returns a reference (like pointer), we can delete the Set method of the property.

Type of the property:

```
PROPERTY Data : REFERENCE TO ST_Cooling
```

Code of the added PROPERTY's Get():

```
//FB_Cooling.Data (Get)

//Return reference to the data struct
Data REF= Data_;
```

Now it's possible to read and edit the data from anywhere where the instance of the function block can be accessed.

```
PROGRAM PRG_Test
VAR
    CoolingSystem : FB_Cooling;
END_VAR

//This is how we read
IF CoolingSystem.Data.CurrentTemperature > 40.0 THEN
    //This is how to write (because it is a reference)
    CoolingSystem.Data.RunCooling := TRUE;
END_IF

//Run the block
CoolingSystem();
```

Perhaps this image also explains what does it look like in the project. See the Data property and it's Get, which is added automatically.

[image]

This is just an example, and a real system would have much more code and data. There could (should?) be also more structs, each for commands, statuses and parameters. But it's just my opinion :)

Comment: Interesting, I guess this would then be the "interface" to the PRG POU. Would you suggest having one program for each "subsystem"? Would it be wise to also have a method SetData() for this PRG?

Comment: In my architecture, I always split the program into small pieces. I often make those systems to be function blocks so it's easy to make many instances. If your system has "subsystems" that won't be copied (so just one cooling system or so) then the PROGRAM would be a good solution. **I added an example to my answer**

Answer (score 0):

A `VAR` in the `PRG_POU` is the equivalent of a local variable in a standard OOP type language.  If you want an object instance/information that can be used in different POUs then the GVL (global variable list) is where you would want to put it.  But if a variable is only going to be used in 1 `POU` then you would want to make this a `VAR` in that `POU`.  From a "best practice" standpoint you usually always want to limit your global variables to the smallest possible number and use more local `VAR` to the `POU` as possible.